# Incorrect Number of Arguments, expected 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cc

I'm doing this avoider game tutorial for my class for me to better understand actionscript, the game is finished quite yet, but it's supposed to stop after initial contact with the Enemy. I am receiving an error saying "Incorrect Number of Arguments, expected 2." And it's singling out line 13, which is the enemy = newEnemy();. Is it something as simple as a missing bracket? I'll post the class below as well.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class AvoiderGame extends MovieClip {

        public var enemy:Enemy;
        public var gameTimer:Timer;
        public var avatar:Avatar;
        public function AvoiderGame() {
            enemy = new Enemy();
            addChild( enemy );
            avatar = new Avatar();
            addChild( avatar );
            avatar.x = mouseX;
            avatar.y = mouseY;

            gameTimer = new Timer( 25 );
            gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
            gameTimer.start();
        }
        public function onTick( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void 
        {
            enemy.moveDownABit();
            avatar.x = mouseX;
            avatar.y = mouseY;

            if ( avatar.hitTestObject( enemy ) ) 
            {
                gameTimer.stop();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Enemy extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Enemy(startX:Number, startY:Number)
        {
            x = startX;
            y = startY;
        }

        public function moveDownABit():void 
        {
            y = y + 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Enemy` class has two params : `startX` and `startY`, so in this case, to create an instance of that class you have to do :

```
var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(value_of_startX, value_of_startY);
```

Otherwise, the compiler will fire that error : "Incorrect Number of Arguments, expected 2.".

But if you want to create an instance of your class without mentioning the `startX` and `startY`, you can just set some default values to your params like this :

```
// your class

// here our default values are : 0, 0
public function Enemy(startX:Number = 0, startY:Number = 0)
{
    x = startX;
    y = startY;
}
```

And then you can call it with params or without, as you like.

Hope that can help.